# Can't GET file from Google Drive SDK in Javascript

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the contents of a file stored in Google Drive through JavaScript.  I have been able to download the file manually just fine by pasting the URL (the webContentLink from the JSON response to a list query) in my browser.
Their SDK doesn't support this natively (the get command only gives you the metadata), so I'm trying using jQuery, and running into a CORS issue even though I've set my site as the origin when I created my Google OAuth client ID & secret.  My code is like:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-9B62bXdQ1nTFlwY0pveVgzOVU&export=download",
          headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token}
        })
```

I get a 405 Method not allowed error:
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-9B62bXdQ1nTFlwY0pveVgzOVU&export=download 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-9B62bXdQ1nTFlwY0pveVgzOVU&export=download. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

According to [this video](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/800483695-3001), Google Drive should support CORS requests.  But according to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=47), it is not working.  Is there any way to do this without using a server-side proxy or some iframe hack?

Comment: use the downloadUrl (for an alient file type) or exportLinks (for a google doc type)

Comment: I tried switching to the downloadUrl (for a text file I uploaded) but I now get a 403 forbidden error.  Am I sending the auth token correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Once I switched to using the latest downloadUrl (this URL changes frequently) and sent the authorization header, I was able to get the contents of the file perfectly.

Comment: what is the "downloadUrl" and how do you get it?